# Calculate How Fast an Object Was Moving at a Particular Time

Tags: algebra-precalculus, statistics

The question is based from a table (posted below):

> Approximately how fast was the ball traveling when $t = 1.0$?

[image]

I calculated the average speed of the ball during the first second ($16$ ft/sec), the average speed during the half-second interval (from $t = 0.5$ to $t = 1.0$) which was $24$ ft/sec, the average speed from $t = 0.9$ to $t = 1.0$ ($30$ ft/sec) and from $t = 1.0$ to $t = 1.1$ (which was $34$ ft/sec). However, I do not know how to use that information to solve for the individual speed of the ball at $t = 1.0$. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Indeed, there isn't enough info to solve for the exact speed. That's why you have to approximate it. Both 30ft/sec and 34 ft/sec are equally valid approximations. Note the negative if they're interested in direction.

Comment: Try taking the average of the results you got for the time intervals $[0.9, 1.0]$ and $[1.0, 1.1]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig The average of the two time intervals would be $32$ ft/sec. I understand why I need to take the average of those two time intervals, however, for finding the approximate speed of the ball when $t = 1.8$ what time intervals do you suggest that I need to use?

Comment: Another way to do this, giving yet another approximation, is to observe that at time t= 0.9, h= 67.0 and, at time t= 1.1, h= 60.6.  So in the .2 second interval, centered at t= 1, the object has moved 60.6- 67= -6.4 so the average speed is -6.4/2= -3.2 ft/sec.  And note the speed **is** negative.

Comment: @user247327  You should have divided by $0.2$ to get $-6.4/0.2 = -32~\text{ft}/\text{s}$.

Comment: @geo_freak  At $t = 1.8$, I would average the speeds (or velocities) you find in the time intervals $[1.7, 1.8]$ and $[1.8, 1.9]$ or, equivalently, find the average speed (or velocity) for the time interval $[1.7, 1.9]$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Should I use speed or velocity because if I use the former than I think that I will be putting the greater height minus the lesser height. However, for the latter, I will do the lesser height minus the greater height.

Comment: The wording "How fast ..." suggests that you should use speed.  The question does not ask about the direction in which the ball was traveling, nor does it explicitly ask for the velocity.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig When it asks to find the approx. speed for $t = 2.2$ I would only have the time interval $[2.1, 2.2]$ but not from $[2.2, 2.3]$. How can I solve it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the statement of the equation "Approximately how fast was the ball moving when $t = 1.0~\text{s}$?" suggests that we are interested in its instantaneous speed rather than its instantaneous velocity at $t = 1.0~\text{s}$ since no direction is specified.

The table provides the height of the ball at time intervals of $0.1~\text{s}$.  What we want to approximate is its instantaneous speed at $t = 1.0~\text{s}$.

The average speed of the ball over a time interval $t$ is 
$$v_{av} = \frac{|\Delta h|}{\Delta t}$$
where $\Delta h$ is the change in its height and $\Delta t$ is the length of the time interval during which that change occurs.  The instantaneous speed is 
$$v = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{|\Delta h|}{\Delta t}$$
Since we only know the height of the object at discrete time intervals, we can best approximate how fast the ball is moving by finding how far the ball moves in the smallest time interval that includes $t = 1.0~\text{s}$.

There are two such intervals, $[0.9, 1.0]$ and $[1.0, 1.1]$.  During the first interval, the ball falls $(67.0 - 64.0)~\text{ft} = 3.0~\text{ft}$.  During the second time interval, the ball falls $(64.0 - 60.6)~\text{ft} = 3.4~\text{ft}$.  Averaging these two results gives 
$$v_{av} = \frac{3.0 + 3.4}{2 \cdot 0.1}~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} = \frac{6.4}{0.2}~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} = 32~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}$$
Equivalently, we could find the average velocity over the time interval $[0.9, 1.1]$.

Not coincidentally, this happens to be how fast we would expect the ball to be moving in free ball in the Earth's gravitational field.  If an object is in free ball, its speed $t~\text{s}$ after it begins falling is 
$$v = gt$$
where $g = 32~\text{ft}/\text{s}$ (in English units).

In the comments, you asked about finding the approximate speed at $t = 1.8~\text{s}$.  If we find the average over the time interval $[1.7, 1.9]$, we obtain 
$$v_{av} = \frac{33.8 - 22.2}{1.8 - 1.6}~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} = \frac{11.6}{0.2}~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} = 58~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}$$
Applying the formula $v = gt$ when $t = 1.8~\text{s}$ gives 
$$v = 32~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} \cdot 1.8~\text{s} = 57.6~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}} \approx 58~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}$$
We cannot directly compute the speed of the ball $2.2~\text{s}$ after it is released.  If we *assume* that we are dealing with a ball in free fall (no air resistance, no initial velocity), then we could use the formula $v = gt$ to approximate its speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can fit it to a local curve.  Let $h(t) = a+bt+ct^2$ where $a, b, c$ are constants.  Use the set of data points to find the constants $t=(.9, 1, 1.1)$ and $h=(67,64,60.6)$ by evaluating $h(t)$ at each point and then solve the non-linear system for $a,b,c$.  At this point, you can take the derivative of $h$ which is $\dfrac{dh}{dt}(t) = b + 2ct$ and evaluate at $t=1$ to get the velocity.

Comment: This is the hard way, however, it places the approximation in the curve fit instead of the the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

$$h(t)=-16t^2 + v_0t + 80$$
$$h(1) = 64 = -16+v_0+80=64+v_0\implies v_0=0$$

Therefore, $$h(t) = -16t^2+80$$

Taking the derivative gives $$\dot h(t)=-32t$$

Finally,
$$\dot h(1) = -32$$

so the object is moving at 32 feet per second downward.